# Binging string with image tag - Windows Phone 8.1 UWP

Tags: c#, xaml, xslt, windows-phone-8.1

I am working in Windows phone 8.1 UWP. I need to bind a string which may have image and video tag in a windows phone component. I used Rich-text box control to bind the string

Below is the sample string which have img tag

```
கொழும்பு:<br /><br />
 தஞ்சம் அடைந்துள்ளனர்.<br /><br /><br /><img alt="" src="/uploads/0F05D1DA-EFC1-4242-B313-C56CD0857B6E_L_styvpf.gif" height="350" width="615" /><br /><br />
இந்நிலையில், இலங்கையின் மத்தியப் பகுதியில்
```

Below is my XAML code to bind the string

```
xmlns:local="using:NameSpace"

<RichTextBlock local:Properties.Html="{Binding ArticleDetail}" />
```

I have install **RichTextBlock.Html2Xaml** from Nuget in my project.I have also added **RichTextBlockHtml2Xaml.xslt** and **RichTextBlockProperties.cs** files in my project

***RichTextBlockHtml2Xaml.xslt***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl"
>
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <!-- The html root element must be div, it translates to a xaml richtextblock.-->
  <xsl:template match="/div" priority="9">
    <RichTextBlock>
      <RichTextBlock.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="Bullet" TargetType="Ellipse">
          <Setter Property="Fill" Value="Black" />
          <Setter Property="Width" Value="6" />
          <Setter Property="Height" Value="6" />
          <Setter Property="Margin" Value="-30,0,0,1" />
        </Style>
        <Style x:Key="Link" TargetType="HyperlinkButton">
          <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0" />
          <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="11" />
          <Setter Property="Margin" Value="-15,-11" />
        </Style>
      </RichTextBlock.Resources>
      <xsl:if test="normalize-space(text()) != ''">
        <Paragraph><xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(text())" /></Paragraph>
      </xsl:if>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="/div/*" />
    </RichTextBlock>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="div" priority="0">
    <Span><xsl:apply-templates /></Span>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- XAML Paragraphs cannot contain paragraphs, so we convert top-level html paragraphs to xaml paragraphs and convert nested html paragraphs to xaml spans with linebreaks -->
  <xsl:template match="/div/P | /div/p" priority="9">
    <Paragraph><xsl:apply-templates /></Paragraph>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="P | p" priority="0">
    <Span><LineBreak /><xsl:apply-templates /><LineBreak /></Span>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- The RichTextBlock XAML element can contain only paragraph child elements, so any unknown html child elements of the root element will become XAML paragraphs -->
  <xsl:template match="/div/*">
    <Paragraph><xsl:apply-templates /></Paragraph>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- Lists can only occur outside paragraphs, at the top level -->
  <xsl:template match="/div/UL | /div/ul"><xsl:apply-templates /></xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="/div/UL/LI | /div/ul/LI | /div/UL/li | /div/ul/li" priority="9" >
    <Paragraph Margin="20,0,0,0"><Span><InlineUIContainer><Ellipse Style="{{StaticResource Bullet}}"/></InlineUIContainer><xsl:apply-templates /><LineBreak /></Span></Paragraph>
  </xsl:template>
  <!-- An UL can only contain LI, so ignore all other elements within an UL -->
  <xsl:template match="/div/UL/* | /div/ul/*" priority="8" />

  <xsl:template match="B | b | STRONG | strong">
    <Bold><xsl:apply-templates /></Bold>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="I | i">
    <Italic><xsl:apply-templates /></Italic>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="U | u">
    <Underline><xsl:apply-templates /></Underline>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="BR | br" priority="0" >
    <LineBreak />
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="A | a">
    <Span><InlineUIContainer><HyperlinkButton Style="{{StaticResource Link}}"><xsl:attribute name="NavigateUri"><xsl:value-of select="@href"/></xsl:attribute><xsl:apply-templates /></HyperlinkButton></InlineUIContainer></Span>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="IMG | img">
    <Span><InlineUIContainer><Image Stretch="None" ><xsl:attribute name="Source"><xsl:value-of select="@src"/></xsl:attribute><xsl:apply-templates /></Image></InlineUIContainer></Span>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- Note that by default, the text content of any unmatched HTML elements will be copied in the XAML. -->
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

***RichTextBlockProperties.cs***

```
public class Properties : DependencyObject
    {
        public static readonly DependencyProperty HtmlProperty =
            DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("Html", typeof(string), typeof(Properties), new PropertyMetadata(null, HtmlChanged));

        public static void SetHtml(DependencyObject obj, string value)
        {
            obj.SetValue(HtmlProperty, value);
        }

        public static string GetHtml(DependencyObject obj)
        {
            return (string)obj.GetValue(HtmlProperty);
        }

        private static async void HtmlChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            // Get the target RichTextBlock
            RichTextBlock richText = d as RichTextBlock;
            if (richText == null) return;

            // Wrap the value of the Html property in a div and convert it to a new RichTextBlock
            string xhtml = string.Format("<div>{0}</div>", e.NewValue as string);
            xhtml = xhtml.Replace("\r", "").Replace("\n", "<br />");
            RichTextBlock newRichText = null;
            if (Windows.ApplicationModel.DesignMode.DesignModeEnabled)
            {
                // In design mode we swallow all exceptions to make editing more friendly
                string xaml = "";
                try
                {
                    xaml = await ConvertHtmlToXamlRichTextBlock(xhtml);
                    newRichText = (RichTextBlock)XamlReader.Load(xaml);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    string errorxaml = string.Format(@"
                        <RichTextBlock 
                         xmlns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation'
                         xmlns:x='http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml'
                        >
                            <Paragraph>An exception occurred while converting HTML to XAML: {0}</Paragraph>
                            <Paragraph />
                            <Paragraph>HTML:</Paragraph>
                            <Paragraph>{1}</Paragraph>
                            <Paragraph />
                            <Paragraph>XAML:</Paragraph>
                            <Paragraph>{2}</Paragraph>
                        </RichTextBlock>",
                        ex.Message,
                        EncodeXml(xhtml),
                        EncodeXml(xaml)
                    );
                    newRichText = (RichTextBlock)XamlReader.Load(errorxaml);
                } // Display a friendly error in design mode.
            }
            else
            {
                // When not in design mode, we let the application handle any exceptions
                string xaml = "";
                try
                {
                    xaml = await ConvertHtmlToXamlRichTextBlock(xhtml);
                    newRichText = (RichTextBlock)XamlReader.Load(xaml);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    string errorxaml = string.Format(@"
                        <RichTextBlock 
                         xmlns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation'
                         xmlns:x='http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml'
                        >
                            <Paragraph>Cannot convert HTML to XAML. Please ensure that the HTML content is valid.</Paragraph>
                            <Paragraph />
                            <Paragraph>HTML:</Paragraph>
                            <Paragraph>{0}</Paragraph>
                        </RichTextBlock>",
                        EncodeXml(xhtml)
                    );
                    newRichText = (RichTextBlock)XamlReader.Load(errorxaml);
                } // Display a friendly error in design mode.
            }

            // Move the blocks in the new RichTextBlock to the target RichTextBlock
            richText.Blocks.Clear();
            if (newRichText != null)
            {
                for (int i = newRichText.Blocks.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
                {
                    Block b = newRichText.Blocks[i];
                    newRichText.Blocks.RemoveAt(i);
                    richText.Blocks.Insert(0, b);
                }
            }
        }

        private static string EncodeXml(string xml)
        {
            string encodedXml = xml.Replace("&", "&amp;").Replace("<", "&lt;").Replace(">", "&gt;").Replace("\"", "&quot;").Replace("'", "&apos;");
            return encodedXml;
        }

        private static XsltProcessor Html2XamlProcessor;

        private static async Task<string> ConvertHtmlToXamlRichTextBlock(string xhtml)
        {
            // Load XHTML fragment as XML document
            XmlDocument xhtmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
            xhtmlDoc.LoadXml(xhtml);

            if (Html2XamlProcessor == null)
            {
                // Read XSLT. In design mode we cannot access the xslt from the file system (with Build Action = Content), 
                // so we use it as an embedded resource instead:
                Assembly assembly = typeof(Properties).GetTypeInfo().Assembly;
                using (Stream stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("NameSpace.RichTextBlockHtml2Xaml.xslt"))
                {
                    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream);
                    string content = await reader.ReadToEndAsync();
                    XmlDocument html2XamlXslDoc = new XmlDocument();
                    html2XamlXslDoc.LoadXml(content);
                    Html2XamlProcessor = new XsltProcessor(html2XamlXslDoc);
                }
            }

            // Apply XSLT to XML
            string xaml = Html2XamlProcessor.TransformToString(xhtmlDoc.FirstChild);
            return xaml;
        }

    }
```

This **கொழும்பு:** word alone bind in the rich text not remaining

Can anyone guide me what mistake i have done. It would be helpful to overcome the issue i am facing.

**Note:** String may also contain video tag please guide me to bind video also

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the **RichTextBlockProperties.cs** as below

```
public class Properties : DependencyObject
    {
        public static readonly DependencyProperty HtmlProperty =
            DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("Html", typeof(string), typeof(Properties), new PropertyMetadata(null, HtmlChanged));

        /// <summary>
        /// sets the HTML property
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="obj"></param>
        /// <param name="value"></param>
        public static void SetHtml(DependencyObject obj, string value)
        {
            obj.SetValue(HtmlProperty, value);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the HTML property
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="obj"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public static string GetHtml(DependencyObject obj)
        {
            return (string)obj.GetValue(HtmlProperty);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// This is called when the HTML has changed so that we can generate RT content
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="d"></param>
        /// <param name="e"></param>
        private static void HtmlChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            RichTextBlock richText = d as RichTextBlock;
            if (richText == null) return;

            //Generate blocks
            string xhtml = e.NewValue as string;

            string baselink = "";

            List<Block> blocks = GenerateBlocksForHtml(xhtml, baselink);

            //Add the blocks to the RichTextBlock
            try
            {
                richText.Blocks.Clear();
                foreach (Block b in blocks)
                {
                    richText.Blocks.Add(b);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {

                Debug.WriteLine("problems with richtextblock!");
            }

        }

        private static List<Block> GenerateBlocksForHtml(string xhtml, string baselink)
        {
            List<Block> bc = new List<Block>();

            try
            {
                HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
                doc.LoadHtml(xhtml);

                foreach (HtmlNode img in doc.DocumentNode.Descendants("img"))
                {
                    if (!img.Attributes["src"].Value.StartsWith("http"))
                    {
                        img.Attributes["src"].Value = baselink + img.Attributes["src"].Value;
                    }
                }

                Block b = GenerateParagraph(doc.DocumentNode);
                bc.Add(b);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
            }

            return bc;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Cleans HTML text for display in paragraphs
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="input"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        private static string CleanText(string input)
        {
            string clean = Windows.Data.Html.HtmlUtilities.ConvertToText(input);
            //clean = System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlEncode(clean);
            if (clean == "\0")
                clean = "\n";
            return clean;
        }

        private static Block GenerateBlockForTopNode(HtmlNode node)
        {
            return GenerateParagraph(node);
        }


        private static void AddChildren(Paragraph p, HtmlNode node)
        {
            bool added = false;
            foreach (HtmlNode child in node.ChildNodes)
            {
                Inline i = GenerateBlockForNode(child);
                if (i != null)
                {
                    p.Inlines.Add(i);
                    added = true;
                }
            }
            if (!added)
            {
                p.Inlines.Add(new Run() { Text = CleanText(node.InnerText) });
            }
        }

        private static void AddChildren(Span s, HtmlNode node)
        {
            bool added = false;

            foreach (HtmlNode child in node.ChildNodes)
            {
                Inline i = GenerateBlockForNode(child);
                if (i != null)
                {
                    s.Inlines.Add(i);
                    added = true;
                }
            }
            if (!added)
            {
                s.Inlines.Add(new Run() { Text = CleanText(node.InnerText) });
            }
        }

        private static Inline GenerateBlockForNode(HtmlNode node)
        {
            switch (node.Name)
            {
                case "div":
                    return GenerateSpan(node);
                case "p":
                case "P":
                    return GenerateInnerParagraph(node);
                case "img":
                case "IMG":
                    return GenerateImage(node);
                case "a":
                case "A":
                    if (node.ChildNodes.Count >= 1 && (node.FirstChild.Name == "img" || node.FirstChild.Name == "IMG"))
                        return GenerateImage(node.FirstChild);
                    //else if (!node.Attributes["href"].Value.Contains("http://"))
                    //  return  GenerateSpanWNewLine(node);
                    else
                        return GenerateHyperLink(node);
                case "li":
                case "LI":
                    return GenerateLI(node);
                case "b":
                case "B":
                    return GenerateBold(node);
                case "em":
                case "EM":
                case "i":
                case "I":
                    return GenerateItalic(node);
                case "u":
                case "U":
                    return GenerateUnderline(node);
                case "br":
                case "BR":
                    return new LineBreak();
                case "span":
                case "Span":
                    return GenerateSpan(node);
                case "iframe":
                case "Iframe":
                    return GenerateIFrame(node);
                case "#text":
                    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(node.InnerText))
                        return new Run() { Text = CleanText(node.InnerText) };
                    break;
                case "h1":
                case "H1":
                    return GenerateH1(node);
                case "h2":
                case "H2":
                    return GenerateH2(node);
                case "h3":
                case "H3":
                    return GenerateH3(node);
                case "ul":
                case "UL":
                    return GenerateUL(node);
                default:
                    return GenerateSpanWNewLine(node);
                    //if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(node.InnerText))
                    //    return new Run() { Text = CleanText(node.InnerText) };
                    //break;
            }
            return null;
        }

        private static Inline GenerateLI(HtmlNode node)
        {
            Span s = new Span();
            InlineUIContainer iui = new InlineUIContainer();
            Ellipse ellipse = new Ellipse();
            ellipse.Fill = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);
            ellipse.Width = 6;
            ellipse.Height = 6;
            ellipse.Margin = new Thickness(-30, 0, 0, 1);
            iui.Child = ellipse;
            s.Inlines.Add(iui);
            AddChildren(s, node);
            s.Inlines.Add(new LineBreak());
            return s;
        }

        private static Inline GenerateImage(HtmlNode node)
        {
            Span s = new Span();
            try
            {
                InlineUIContainer iui = new InlineUIContainer();
                var sourceUri = System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlDecode(node.Attributes["src"].Value);
                Image img = new Image() { Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(sourceUri, UriKind.Absolute)) };
                img.Stretch = Stretch.Uniform;
                img.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Top;
                img.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left;
                img.Width = Convert.ToDouble(node.Attributes["width"].Value);
                img.Height = Convert.ToDouble(node.Attributes["height"].Value);
                //img.ImageOpened += img_ImageOpened;
                //img.ImageFailed += img_ImageFailed;
                //    img.Tapped += ScrollingBlogPostDetailPage.img_Tapped;
                iui.Child = img;
                s.Inlines.Add(iui);
                s.Inlines.Add(new LineBreak());
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
            }
            return s;
        }

        //static void img_ImageFailed(object sender, ExceptionRoutedEventArgs e)
        //{
        //    var i = 5;
        //}

        //static void img_ImageOpened(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        //{
        //    Image img = sender as Image;
        //    BitmapImage bimg = img.Source as BitmapImage;
        //    if (bimg.PixelWidth > 800 || bimg.PixelHeight > 600)
        //    {
        //        img.Width = 800; img.Height = 600;
        //        if (bimg.PixelWidth > 800)
        //        {
        //            img.Width = 800;
        //            img.Height = (800.0 / (double)bimg.PixelWidth) * bimg.PixelHeight;
        //        }
        //        if (img.Height > 600)
        //        {
        //            img.Height = 600;
        //            img.Width = (600.0 / (double)img.Height) * img.Width;
        //        }
        //    }
        //    else
        //    {
        //        img.Height = bimg.PixelHeight;
        //        img.Width = bimg.PixelWidth;
        //    }
        //}

        private static Inline GenerateHyperLink(HtmlNode node)
        {
            Span s = new Span();
            InlineUIContainer iui = new InlineUIContainer();

            Debug.WriteLine(node.Attributes["href"].Value);
            HyperlinkButton hb;
            string lk = node.Attributes["href"].Value;
            if (!lk.Contains("http"))
            {
                //lk = string.Format("http://cc.com/{0}", lk);
            }
            hb = new HyperlinkButton() { NavigateUri = new Uri(lk, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute), Content = CleanText(node.InnerText), };

            if (node.ParentNode != null && (node.ParentNode.Name == "li" || node.ParentNode.Name == "LI"))
                hb.Style = (Style)Application.Current.Resources["RTLinkLI"];
            else if ((node.NextSibling == null || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(node.NextSibling.InnerText)) && (node.PreviousSibling == null || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(node.PreviousSibling.InnerText)))
                hb.Style = (Style)Application.Current.Resources["RTLinkOnly"];
            else
                hb.Style = (Style)Application.Current.Resources["RTLink"];

            iui.Child = hb;

            s.Inlines.Add(iui);

            return s;
        }

        private static Inline GenerateIFrame(HtmlNode node)
        {
            try
            {
                Span s = new Span();
                s.Inlines.Add(new LineBreak());
                InlineUIContainer iui = new InlineUIContainer();
                //WebView ww = new WebView() { Source = new Uri(node.Attributes["src"].Value, UriKind.Absolute)
                //    , Width = Int32.Parse(node.Attributes["width"].Value), Height = Int32.Parse(node.Attributes["height"].Value) };

                int height = 160;
                int width = 300;

                WebView ww = new WebView()
                {
                    Source = new Uri(node.Attributes["src"].Value, UriKind.Absolute)
                    ,
                    Width = width,
                    Height = height
                };

                iui.Child = ww;
                s.Inlines.Add(iui);
                s.Inlines.Add(new LineBreak());
                return s;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return null;
            }
        }

        private static Block GenerateTopIFrame(HtmlNode node)
        {
            try
            {
                Paragraph p = new Paragraph();
                InlineUIContainer iui = new InlineUIContainer();
                WebView ww = new WebView()
                {
                    Source = new Uri(node.Attributes["src"].Value, UriKind.Absolute)
                    ,
                    Width = Int32.Parse(node.Attributes["width"].Value),
                    Height = Int32.Parse(node.Attributes["height"].Value)
                };
                iui.Child = ww;
                p.Inlines.Add(iui);
                return p;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return null;
            }
        }

        private static Inline GenerateBold(HtmlNode node)
        {
            Bold b = new Bold();
            AddChildren(b, node);
            return b;
        }

        private static Inline GenerateUnderline(HtmlNode node)
        {
            Underline u = new Underline();
            AddChildren(u, node);
            return u;
        }

        private static Inline GenerateItalic(HtmlNode node)
        {
            Italic i = new Italic();
            AddChildren(i, node);
            return i;
        }

        private static Block GenerateParagraph(HtmlNode node)
        {
            Paragraph p = new Paragraph();
            AddChildren(p, node);
            return p;
        }

        private static Inline GenerateUL(HtmlNode node)
        {
            Span s = new Span();
            s.Inlines.Add(new LineBreak());
            AddChildren(s, node);
            return s;
        }

        private static Inline GenerateInnerParagraph(HtmlNode node)
        {
            Span s = new Span();
            s.Inlines.Add(new LineBreak());
            AddChildren(s, node);
            s.Inlines.Add(new LineBreak());
            return s;
        }

        private static Inline GenerateSpan(HtmlNode node)
        {
            Span s = new Span();
            AddChildren(s, node);
            return s;
        }

        private static Inline GenerateSpanWNewLine(HtmlNode node)
        {
            Span s = new Span();
            AddChildren(s, node);
            if (s.Inlines.Count > 0)
                s.Inlines.Add(new LineBreak());
            return s;
        }

        private static Span GenerateH3(HtmlNode node)
        {
            Span s = new Span() { FontSize = (double)Application.Current.Resources["H3"] };
            s.Inlines.Add(new LineBreak());
            Bold bold = new Bold();
            Run r = new Run() { Text = CleanText(node.InnerText) };
            bold.Inlines.Add(r);
            s.Inlines.Add(bold);
            s.Inlines.Add(new LineBreak());
            return s;
        }

        private static Inline GenerateH2(HtmlNode node)
        {
            Span s = new Span() { FontSize = (double)Application.Current.Resources["H2"] };
            s.Inlines.Add(new LineBreak());
            Run r = new Run() { Text = CleanText(node.InnerText) };
            s.Inlines.Add(r);
            s.Inlines.Add(new LineBreak());
            return s;
        }

        private static Inline GenerateH1(HtmlNode node)
        {
            //(Style)Application.Current.Resources["RTLinkLI"]
            Span s = new Span() { FontSize = (double)Application.Current.Resources["H1"] };
            s.Inlines.Add(new LineBreak());
            Run r = new Run() { Text = CleanText(node.InnerText) };
            s.Inlines.Add(r);
            s.Inlines.Add(new LineBreak());
            return s;
        }

        #region old stuff

        private static XsltProcessor Html2XamlProcessor;

        private static async Task<string> ConvertHtmlToXamlRichTextBlock(string xhtml)
        {
            // Load XHTML fragment as XML document
            XmlDocument xhtmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
            if (Windows.ApplicationModel.DesignMode.DesignModeEnabled)
            {
                // In design mode we swallow all exceptions to make editing more friendly
                try { xhtmlDoc.LoadXml(xhtml); }
                catch { } // For some reason code in catch is not executed when an exception occurs in design mode, so we can't display a friendly error here.
            }
            else
            {
                // When not in design mode, we let the application handle any exceptions
                xhtmlDoc.LoadXml(xhtml);
            }

            if (Html2XamlProcessor == null)
            {
                // Read XSLT. In design mode we cannot access the xslt from the file system (with Build Action = Content), 
                // so we use it as an embedded resource instead:
                Assembly assembly = typeof(Properties).GetTypeInfo().Assembly;
                using (Stream stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("Namespace.RichTextBlockHtml2Xaml.xslt"))
                {
                    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream);
                    string content = await reader.ReadToEndAsync();
                    XmlDocument html2XamlXslDoc = new XmlDocument();
                    html2XamlXslDoc.LoadXml(content);
                    Html2XamlProcessor = new XsltProcessor(html2XamlXslDoc);
                }
            }

            // Apply XSLT to XML
            string xaml = Html2XamlProcessor.TransformToString(xhtmlDoc.FirstChild);
            return xaml;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Convert HTML to Rich textblock controls
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="xhtml"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        private static async Task<string> ConvertHtmlToXamlRichTextBlock2(string xhtml)
        {
            string xaml = "<?xml version=\"1.0\"?><RichTextBlock xmlns=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation\" xmlns:x=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml\">";

            try
            {
                HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
                doc.LoadHtml(xhtml);

                foreach (HtmlNode node in doc.DocumentNode.ChildNodes)
                {
                    xaml += GenerateBlockForTopNode(node);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
            }

            xaml += "</RichTextBlock>";

            return xaml;
        }

        private static string GenerateBlockForTopNode_old(HtmlNode node)
        {
            string result = "";

            switch (node.Name)
            {
                case "h1":
                case "H1":
                    result = string.Format("<Paragraph FontSize=\"30\">{0}</Paragraph>", CleanText(node.InnerText));
                    break;
                case "h2":
                case "H2":
                    result = string.Format("<Paragraph FontSize=\"24\">{0}</Paragraph>", CleanText(node.InnerText));
                    break;
                case "h3":
                case "H3":
                    result = string.Format("<Paragraph><Bold>{0}</Bold></Paragraph>", CleanText(node.InnerText));
                    break;
                case "ul":
                case "UL":
                    result = String.Format("<Paragraph Margin=\"20,0,0,0\"><LineBreak />{0}</Paragraph>", GenerateBlockForChildren(node));
                    break;
                default:
                    //var text = GenerateBlockForChildren(node);
                    //if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(text))
                    //{
                    //    result = String.Format("<Paragraph>{0}</Paragraph>", text);
                    //}
                    //else
                    //{
                    //    result = "";
                    //}
                    result = String.Format("<Paragraph>{0}</Paragraph>", GenerateBlockForChildren(node));
                    break;
            }

            return result;
        }

        private static string GenerateBlockForNode_old(HtmlNode node)
        {
            string result = "";

            switch (node.Name)
            {
                case "div":
                    result = String.Format("<Span>{0}</Span>", GenerateBlockForChildren(node));
                    break;
                case "p":
                case "P":
                    result = String.Format("<Span><LineBreak />{0}<LineBreak /></Span>", GenerateBlockForChildren(node));
                    break;
                case "img":
                case "IMG":
                    {


                        //if (int.Parse(node.Attributes["width"].Value) > 500)
                        //    result = "<Span><InlineUIContainer><Image Style=\"{StaticResource RTImage}\" Width=\"500\" Source=\"" + node.Attributes["src"].Value + "\"></Image></InlineUIContainer></Span>";

                        //else
                        result = "<Span><InlineUIContainer><Image Style=\"{StaticResource RTImage}\" Source=\"" + node.Attributes["src"].Value + "\"></Image></InlineUIContainer></Span>";
                    }
                    break;
                case "a":
                case "A":
                    if (node.ChildNodes.Count == 1 && (node.FirstChild.Name == "img" || node.FirstChild.Name == "IMG"))
                        result = GenerateBlockForChildren(node);
                    else
                    {
                        if (node.ParentNode != null && (node.ParentNode.Name == "li" || node.ParentNode.Name == "LI"))
                            result = "<Span><InlineUIContainer><HyperlinkButton Style=\"{StaticResource RTLinkLI}\" NavigateUri=\"" + node.Attributes["href"].Value + "\">" + CleanText(node.InnerText) + "</HyperlinkButton></InlineUIContainer></Span>";
                        else if ((node.NextSibling == null || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(node.NextSibling.InnerText)) && (node.PreviousSibling == null || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(node.PreviousSibling.InnerText)))
                            result = "<Span><InlineUIContainer><HyperlinkButton Style=\"{StaticResource RTLinkOnly}\" NavigateUri=\"" + node.Attributes["href"].Value + "\">" + CleanText(node.InnerText) + "</HyperlinkButton></InlineUIContainer></Span>";
                        else
                            result = "<Span><InlineUIContainer><HyperlinkButton Style=\"{StaticResource RTLink}\" NavigateUri=\"" + node.Attributes["href"].Value + "\">" + CleanText(node.InnerText) + "</HyperlinkButton></InlineUIContainer></Span>";
                    }
                    break;
                case "li":
                case "LI":
                    result = "<Span><InlineUIContainer><Ellipse Style=\"{StaticResource RTBullet}\"/></InlineUIContainer>" + GenerateBlockForChildren(node) + "<LineBreak /></Span>";
                    break;
                case "b":
                case "B":
                    result = String.Format("<Bold>{0}</Bold>", GenerateBlockForChildren(node));
                    break;
                case "i":
                case "I":
                    result = String.Format("<Italic>{0}</Italic>", GenerateBlockForChildren(node));
                    break;
                case "u":
                case "U":
                    result = String.Format("<Underline>{0}</Underline>", GenerateBlockForChildren(node));
                    break;
                case "br":
                case "BR":
                    result = "<LineBreak />";
                    break;
                case "span":
                case "Span":
                    result = String.Format("<Span>{0}</Span>", GenerateBlockForChildren(node));
                    break;
                case "#text":
                    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(node.InnerText))
                        result = CleanText(node.InnerText);
                    else
                        result = "";
                    break;
                default:
                    result = CleanText(node.InnerText);
                    break;
            }

            return result;
        }

        private static string GenerateBlockForChildren(HtmlNode node)
        {
            string result = "";
            foreach (HtmlNode child in node.ChildNodes)
            {
                result += GenerateBlockForNode(child);
            }
            if (result == "")
                result = CleanText(node.InnerText);
            return result;
        }

        #endregion

    }
```

Will get the desired output